# How to update redux state without creating new array

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, flatlist

```
export const initialState = {
   data: [1,2,3]
}
```

after success api request i am updating data state

```
 data: state.data.concat(...action.data.data)
```

All the flat list items are getting re-render as concat is returning new array.(onReachEnd i am calling api for next page. and that data needs to added in redux state without updating whole array )

Answer (score 1):

You can just destructure both

```js
data : [...state.data, ...action.data.data]
```